Communicating 1/4 miles without Wi-Fi. (I want to design a driveway alarm.)
We live in a very rural area of Ohio. Our driveway is 0.25 miles (400 m) long. I would like to design an alarm that will alert us when someone turns into our driveway.
The easy part is the optical interrupt circuit. And I plan to power it with a battery, and keep the battery charged using a small PV array. But how am I going to get the signal to the house?
I do not want to dig a ditch and lay a cable. So I need some kind of RF solution.
We have Wi-Fi at the house. But there's no Wi-Fi signal at the end of the driveway.
So what are my options? Is there a way the unit can communicate with the cell phone tower? How would that work? Would that be like owning another cell phone on our cellular plan? (Even then, there's not a good cell signal at the end of the driveway, so I'm not sure if this would work even if there was a hardware solution.)
So perhaps a direct RF link is best. Is there a company to make modular transmitters & receivers that are FCC compliant?
Just looking for ideas. Thanks!
Michael

What is the signal format that you are transmitting? Is there a microprocessor in the remote unit? 1/4 mile with a directional antenna is very doable for WiFi.

LoRa was made for these kinds of low bitrate, long range problems.  You could also buy an IOT SIM and a cheap 4G cell module for ~10 dollars a year, but you're close enough you may not need that.

1400 feet with nothing in the way is pretty straightforward. You might be able to do it with a long range wireless doorbell... Some are advertised to be able to transmit up to a mile.

Alarm System - 1/2 Mile Long Range Wireless Driveway Alarm Outdoor Weather Resistant Motion Sensor & Detector  And it is too cute.

If you want to build something yourself: I would go with LoRa (Wikipedia link). It is low power and high range at the cost of transmission speed. It can easily cover 1 mile.
For a starter, get yourself familiar with the things network

Agree with 900MHz. As this is electrical engineering, you may just want to have the driveway booby trapped to send a continuous wave signal in the ISM band and monitor that in the house like a doorbell.
